# Typescript return type inference

Tags: typescript

In the following code snippet, typescript is able to infer the return type correctly:

```js
{
  type IOFunction< OUTPUT> = (input: number) => OUTPUT

  function createIOFunction<OUTPUT>(input: number, converter: IOFunction<OUTPUT>): OUTPUT {
    return converter(input)
  }

  const x = createIOFunction(12, num => num + '!')
  // x is of type 'string'. Typescript was able to infer the OUTPUT type correctly AND without me specifying what the output type should be

  const y = createIOFunction(24, num => num * 2)
  // y is of type 'number'
}
```

How can I achieve this with following construct?

```js
{
  type IOFunction<INPUT> = (input: INPUT) => any /* <-- What goes here ?? */
  // I don't want the type to be IOFunction<INPUT, OUTPUT> = (input: INPUT) => OUTPUT

  const convert: IOFunction<number> = num => num + '!'
  const x = convert(12)
  // x is of type any, not string
  // how can x be inferred? 
}
```

Here a more complex example (as requested):

```js
  interface STATE {
    value: number
  }

  const myState: STATE = {
    value: 12
  } 

  type FAC_FUNCTION<S> = (state: S) => any


  const factory: FAC_FUNCTION<STATE> = state => (
    {
      hello() { 
        return 'Hello ' + state.value;
      }
    })

  const toolbox = factory(myState)
  // toolbox.hello() <!--- not typed :(




  type FACTORY_FUNCTION<S, OUTPUT> = (state:S) => OUTPUT

  function bindFactory<S, OUTPUT>(state:S, fac: FACTORY_FUNCTION<S, OUTPUT>) {
    return fac(state)
  }

  const toolbox2 = bindFactory(myState, state => ({
    hello() {
      return 'Hello ' + state.value
    }
  }))

  toolbox2.hello() // typed :)
```

The toolbox is not typed, toolbox2 is. I want to bind the state to the specific functions. In the end i wan't the user to write something like `const toolbox = bindFactory(state, factory)`.

Sorry, but this is the best complex example I came up with

Comment: What's the problem with `IOFunction<INPUT, OUTPUT> = (input: INPUT) => OUTPUT`?

Comment: In the examples the OUTPUTs are simple values. In my real world app the OUTPUT will be a complex object. The user of this function should not be bothered with writing the type definition of that complex object.

Comment: Can you please make an example? Normally you don't need to specify the entire complex objects. In my experience this is not a problem in the real world.

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with your `bindFactory()`?  That's the solution I would expect and it works the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured a way - and it is actually very simple. All you have to provide are the type definitions of the input parameters and let the compiler figure out the rest.

So instead of

```
  type FAC_FUNCTION<S> = (state: S) => any

  const factory: FAC_FUNCTION<STATE> = state => (
    {
      hello() { 
        return 'Hello ' + state.value;
      }
    })

  const toolbox = factory(myState)
```

use:

```js
  const factory = (state:PROPS) => (
    {
      hello() { 
        return 'Hello ' + state.value;
      }
    })

  const toolbox = factory(myState)
```